# What is the best way to build Angular 4 app on top of Asp.NET Core?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I did try these two templates:

https://github.com/asadsahi/AspNetCoreSpa

https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal

But in both cases ended up with something not working property.

I just wonder if it is possible to somehow run AngularCLI on top of .net core? 'Im new to Angular, so bear with me please.

I'm looking for something which will give me all the sweets like AOT,DLL, TreeShaking with a minimal/zero configuration on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The SpaTemplates have been updated to Angular 4 which means that you should be able to get SSR along with other benefits without having to strip things out. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates

---

**ORIGINAL:** It sounds like what you're looking for is a template that may not fully exist out in the wild. If you want .NET Core, Angular 4, HMR, and Webpack, you can start with the Angular SPA Templates that are currently using Angular 2.

Run the following at the command line.

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
dotnet new angular
```

(Pulled from https://jonhilton.net/2017/02/21/create-a-vs2017-angular-2-and-net-core-site-using-the-command-line/)

Then you can modify the project using the follow changes to remove Angular 2 Universal and Server Side Rendering in order to be able to upgrade to Angular 4.

**webpack.config.vendor.js**

Remove angular2-universal from vendor section
Remove angular2-universal-polyfills from vendor section
Remove serverBundleConfig
Replace:

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')),
```

with:

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')),
```

**webpack.config.js**

Remove serverBundleConfig

**package.json**

Added angular/animation, core-js, es6-promise
Upgraded angular packages to ^4.0.0
Removed angular2-universal, angular2-universal-patch, angular2-universal-polyfills, isomorphic-fetch
Upgraded other packages to the latest versions at the time

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

Removed asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server"

**ClientApp/polyfills/polyfills.ts**

Added this file with the following:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'zone.js';
```

**ClientApp/boot-server.ts**

Deleted this file

**ClientApp/boot-client.ts**

Changed the file to the following:

```
import './polyfills/polyfills.ts';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
const rootElemTagName = 'app'; // Update this if you change your root component selector

// Enable either Hot Module Reloading or production mode
if (module['hot']) {
    module['hot'].accept();
    module['hot'].dispose(() => {
        // Before restarting the app, we create a new root element and dispose the old one
        const oldRootElem = document.querySelector(rootElemTagName);
        const newRootElem = document.createElement(rootElemTagName);
        oldRootElem.parentNode.insertBefore(newRootElem, oldRootElem);
        platform.destroy();
    });
} else {
    enableProdMode();
}

// Boot the application, either now or when the DOM content is loaded
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();

const bootApplication = () => { platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule); };
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    bootApplication();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bootApplication);
}
```

**ClientApp/app/app.module.ts**

Replaced UniversalModule in the import at the top with:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Replaced UniversalModule in the imports area with:

```
BrowserModule,
HttpModule,
```

When this is all done, I run the following commands:

```
npm prune
npm install
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

(Pulled from https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/938)

I've verified that this will get Angular 4 running on .NET core and still allow for HMR and Webpack to work.

Comment: I was using that "template" but had to leave it because of lack of ng4 support. I will try what you have suggested and let you know. Thank you very much.

Comment: We were in the same situation until we realized the only thing holding us back from upgrading everything else was server side rendering, which wasn't a necessity for us and added a lot of additional complexity that didn't seem to be entirely worked out yet in its final implementation.

Comment: This sounds great! I will try it today. Thank you.

Comment: The team just released a new version of the SpaTemplates that should get you everything you need, and use Angular 4. I'll update the answer to reflect.

Comment: If this solution works for you, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Not yet fully migrated. I will if it solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

What i can suggest to you is.. `if you don't need a SERVER SIDE RENDERING (aka Angular Universal) I strongly suggest to you to completely separate the two layers` (Front end Angular 4 app) and Back end (Asp.NET WebAPI or MVC Asp.NET CORE APP) ...

there are several reason to do so:

1 - `better separation of techonologies`

2- `you can publish the front end and back end in separate sites or separate Servers`!!

3 - `if you need to scale` (up or horizontal) the back end .. you don't have to do also for front end .. instead if you have both in the same app you can't be so granular

4 - `if you want you can cache` (with your server or with `CDN` .. or with some external services like `cloudfire` and so on..) your front end app .. cause they're only static files... if you've your front end and back end mixed (Razor for index page mixed with html and so on) you can't..

SO i strongly encourage you to think about your decision.

Hope it helps you!!!

Comment: Hi, I was thinking about it but in that case I loose all the benefits the Asp.Net Core host gives me. For example authentication; we allow access only to authenticated users (Azure AD using UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication) so all the requests are actually already authenticated. If I would have client app on a different server I would have to deal with that. Or maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: Yep, I don't need server-side rendering, just AOT, HMR, DLL, TreeShaking etc.

Comment: no .. you can benefit of ALL the .NET (CORE) features like OAUTH .. cause you need (even if is in the same app) to send the OAUTH token innevery request between front and back end server ... and AOT , DLL and so are available .. use angular-cli for Angular so it can help you with all difficult task (if you use webpack you need to do it by yourself)

Comment: maybe you are right, I fee that this is a right approach too, but it introduces some hassle you don't have while hosting both sides at once. I need to do som POC and decide based on that. Isn't angular-cli using webpack now?

Comment: this is definitely the way to go. completely separate, angular cli for client side and regular web api .net core

Answer (score 1):

.NET Core on the backend does not care what framework you use on the frontend. Angular's [Http](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html) module will call your .NET Core WebApi backend endpoint.

During development, you will typically build the Angular CLI TypeScript project with `ng serve` and build the backend inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more specific (did update my question now). I would like to have all the sweets like DLL, AOT, TreeShaking etc. available, idealli with zero configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPA Templates, which are supported by Microsoft, to scaffold an angular and asp.core application.

**Prerequisites:**

- .Net Core SDK 1.0 RC4 (or later) for Win,Mac or Linux
- Node.js (v6 or later)

To install SPA Templates, run the command below:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

To check the list of available Templates run command:

```
dotnet new -l
```

To finally scaffold the application, create a folder/directory and cd into it.
Run the command below within you project folder:

```
dotnet new angular
```

To restore packages and dependencies run the following commands in the order below:

1. `dotnet restore`
2. `npm install`
   Once all dependencies are restored. You can start the application by running command:

   dotnet run

The app will listen on port 5000, so in your browser head to
http://localhost:5000